# How to cast string list into a custom datatype?

Tags: c#, list, csv, types

Background: I'm trying to read from a csv file containing a mix of strings and doubles.  I want to leave the strings as they are for searching and indexing purposes, but be able to perform data analysis on the double value within the list.  I also don't want to read the entire csv file into memory before I separate it into it's different categories, so I'm trying to assign it to a list with a custom data type as it's read from the csv.

How can I cast that single list entry into a double and then add it to the list?

```
class data
{
    public List<string> timefrom { get; set; }
    public List<string> timeto { get; set; }
    public List<string> type { get; set; }        
    public List<string> site { get; set; }
    public List<string> box { get; set; }
    public List<string> group { get; set; }        
    public List<string> sourcecopy { get; set; }
    public List<string> destcopy { get; set; }
    public List<string> gridid { get; set; }        
    public List<string> stat { get; set; }
    public List<double> value { get; set; }
    public List<string> unit { get; set; }
    public List<string> peak { get; set; }
}

class Class1
{
    public List<data> 
        WANtpfromSite, 
        WANtpbyCG, 
        IncomingWritesbyCG, 
        LinkUtilbyCG, 
        BoxUtil, 
        CompressionCPU, 
        ReplicationCPU, 
        CompressionRatio, 
        DeduplicationRatio, 
        IncomingWritesbyBox, 
        IncomingWritesbyBoxReplicating, 
        IObyBox, 
        IObyBoxReplicating, 
        PacketLoss, 
        LineLatency;


    public void getDayData(string directory)
    {

        string[] fileEntries;

        fileEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory + "/home/www/info/long_term_stats");
        string filePath = fileEntries[0];
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
        List<string> Line;
        int row = 1;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            //Splits the line read into a list of string values
            Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList<string>();

            // Here I'll probably use a switch case to set the variable, but this is an example of what it should do.
            if (Line[8] == "Wan Throughput from site")
            {
                //Here is where I'm having the problem - it can't implicitely convert the string list to a data list because
                // of that single double value within the list.  How would I go about explicitely converting the "Line" 
                //variable to a <data> type?

                WANtpfromSite = List < data > datatype;
            }
            row++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: If there's a data type that would allow for this, or a free library I'm not aware of, please let me know!  I'm fairly new to C# (Cut my teeth on MATLAB and all it's easily-converting-data-types glory - so this sort of issue is new to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - the more I looked thorugh things it looks like a group of DataTable elements is what I needed.  Instead of doing a list of lists, I just set up a datatable for each variabletype.